# postgres - how to test if peer of foreign table actually exists

Tags: postgresql, foreign-data-wrapper

I have two databases: let's call them `primary` (which holds actual data) and `fdw` (which contains foreign-data-wrapper of data in primary db).

I create simple table in `primary` db:

```
create schema myschema;
create table myschema.foo (id bigint, whatever text);
create table myschema.foov as select * from foo;
```

I create foreign table in `fdw` db accessing primary table through view:

```
create extension postgres_fdw;
create server remote_docker foreign data wrapper postgres_fdw options (host 'primary', dbname 'postgres', port '5432');
create schema remote_myschema;
create user mapping for current_user server remote_docker options (user 'postgres');
create foreign table remote_myschema.foo (id bigint, whatever text) server remote_docker options (schema_name 'myschema', table_name 'foov');
```

When executing `select * from remote_myschema.foo` query, everything works ok.

The problem: if I didn't create view in `primary` db, the `create foreign table` command in `fdw` db passes without error anyway. I am able to discover the nonexistency of view in `primary` db only at time of query execution on `fdw` db.

The question: is somehow possible to detect that foreign table is bound to nonexistent original? I compared `pg_class` data of foreign table in both cases and didn't find any difference nor anything in documentation. The only way I know at this moment is catching exception

```
do $$
declare
  ex boolean;
begin
  begin
    execute 'select null from remote_myschema.foo';
    ex := true;
  exception when others then
    ex := false;
  end;
  raise notice '%', ex::text;
end;
$$;
```

which is awful.

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to create a foreign table to a system table on the remote server? In that case it would be possible to "mirror" e.g. `pg_tables` locally and you could check that

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Interesting idea I didn't think of (I would upvoted it if you turned it into answer). I tried it in my docker env where I had played with minimized version (`create foreign table foreignclass (relname name, relkind char) server remote_docker options (schema_name 'pg_catalog', table_name 'pg_class');`) and it works. Anyway I will finally stay with exception-based solution since there is restricted access on real production and also I would have to import more catalog tables (at least namespace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching the exception is the only way. Unless views are in the habit of suddenly disappearing at your site, you don't have to test it every time you use the foreign table. Testing once, right after you created it, is good enough.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for confirmation, yes the check is performed in procedure called only on schema change (actually imitating `import foreign schema` for tables containing custom enum types), not on each table access. Actually deployed on prod, works well.